# How to get all alter statements performed on a schema for a given date range?

Tags: db2

I would like to ask if there is a way to get all the alter statements performed on a schema/(all tables within the schema) within db2 (LUW)?

Is there a system logging table I can query for this?

Comment: Please keep in mind that for questions like this, the answer depends completely on which member of the DB2 family you are using. Please specify DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS when asking (or answering) such questions, or indicate with a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an event monitor, this will generate a lot of output, and then you can filter acccoding to your needs.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0005993.html

Comment: perhaps you could summarize the steps here, to protect against future link-rot?